# How to make sequelize add N before Unicode string in its SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, database, node.js, unicode, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize.js and Node.js, Our backend Database is SQL Server 2014, So we use Sequelize.js as an ORM layer, We need to handle non-English char in our data.

when I try to use sequelize create method to insert non-English char, I only get **`???`** in DB, after debugging I found that the reason as below, but I don't know is there any existed good solution to fix it.

Below is one test model I created in my application, I will use sequelize.import method to generate the table schema, then call the fillTestData method to insert test data to DB after I call sync against DB server, but I only get a lot of `'????'` in DB table.

```
var Promise = require("sequelize").Promise;

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Test = sequelize.define("Test", {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },

    Name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    charset: "utf8",
    classMethods: {
      fillTestData: function(models) {

        return Promise.join(
          Test.create({Name: "hello"}),
          Test.create({Name: "aello"}),
          Test.create({Name: "Aello"}),
          Test.create({Name: "bello"}),
          Test.create({Name: "こんにちは"}),
          Test.create({Name: "مرحبا"}),
          Test.create({Name: "ជំរាបសួរ"}),
          Test.create({Name: "მიესალმები"}),
          Test.create({Name: "Hallå"}),
          Test.create({Name: "你好"}),
          Test.create({Name: "我們"}),
          Test.create({Name: "여러분, 안녕하세요"}),
          Test.create({Name: "Всем привет"}),
          Test.create({Name: "ENLE o gbogbo eniyan"}),
          Test.create({Name: "सभी को नमस्कार"}));
      }
    }
  });


  return Test;
};
```

I check Node.js output log, found out that sequelize translate above create request into below SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO [Test] ([Name]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES ('我們');
```

And I checked the Column definition in Database, the Name column is nvarchar, I can insert correct non-English data to DB with below SQL statement:

```
  insert into [Test] values (N'我們')
```

Then I realize that sequelize DON'T add the 'N' before the non-English string in the SQL statement.

Then I try to debug and locate the root cause at "sequelize\lib\sql-string.js" file, sequelize will call its `escapeId` method to escapse value before generate the SQL statement, in this method, it won't check if it need to add the 'N' before a Unicode string for mssql dialect. So I make a little change to this method at the end like below:

```
  if(dialect === 'mssql') {
    return "N'" + val + "'";
  }
  else {
    return "'" + val + "'";    
  }
```

Then I re-run my application, everything can work as my expectation, all Unicode string can be stored to Database correctly now.

But this is not a good fix, I expect sequelize should have consider this kind of requirement and provide some kind of define options like the charset, so I don't need to take care of this by myself.

Does anybody happen to know how to resolve this issue gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), nchar and nvarchar both use the UNICODE UCS-2 character set. Try changing the charset from utf8 to UCS-2 in your test model code..